# I'm trying to not leak activity

Tags: android, multithreading, memory-leaks, handler

I'm studing nfc , and in the while I'm practicing to create a new app without leaking activity.

This is my activity :

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.nfc.NfcAdapter;
import android.nfc.Tag;
import android.nfc.tech.IsoDep;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;

public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private NfcAdapter mNfcAdapter;
    private static WeakReference<HomeActivity> me = null;
    public static final int NFC_DATA_READ = 1;

    private static Handler handler = new Handler() {


        public void handleMessage(Message msg)  {
            if (null != me.get()) return;

            switch (msg.what)  {
                case NFC_DATA_READ:
                    TextView textView = (TextView) me.get().findViewById(R.id.dataText);
                    textView.setText((String) msg.obj);
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        mNfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);

        if (mNfcAdapter == null) {
            // Stop here, we definitely need NFC
            Toast.makeText(this, "This device doesn't support NFC.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
            return;

        }
        handleIntent(getIntent());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mNfcAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setupForegroundDispatch(this,mNfcAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        /**
         * This method gets called, when a new Intent gets associated with the current activity instance.
         * Instead of creating a new activity, onNewIntent will be called. For more information have a look
         * at the documentation.
         *
         * In our case this method gets called, when the user attaches a Tag to the device.
         */
        handleIntent(intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        me = new WeakReference<HomeActivity>(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        me.clear();
        super.onStop();
    }

    private void handleIntent(Intent intent){
        String action = intent.getAction();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"letto qualcosa",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {
            // In case we would still use the Tech Discovered Intent
            Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
            String[] techList = tag.getTechList();
            String searchedTech = IsoDep.class.getName();

            for (String tech : techList) {
                if (searchedTech.equals(tech)) {
                    new ReaderTask(handler).execute(tag);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param activity The corresponding {@link Activity} requesting the foreground dispatch.
     * @param adapter The {@link NfcAdapter} used for the foreground dispatch.
     */
    private void setupForegroundDispatch(final Activity activity, NfcAdapter adapter) {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(activity.getApplicationContext(), activity.getClass());
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

        final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(activity.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);

        IntentFilter[] filters = new IntentFilter[1];
        String[][] techList = new String[][]{};

        // Notice that this is the same filter as in our manifest.
        filters[0] = new IntentFilter();
        filters[0].addAction(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED);

        // Setup a tech list for all NfcF tags
        techList = new String[][] { new String[] { IsoDep.class.getName() } };


        adapter.enableForegroundDispatch(activity, pendingIntent, filters, techList);
    }
}
```

ReaderTask is theorically a long running task.
To not leak activity context I create a new class, but I need to update view with the result of this task. To do that I develop a static inner class Handler inside HomeActivity and the ReaderTask sendMessage to that Handler.
The Handler use a weakreference to the activity to check if the activity is live or not.

But I think there is a best way to do all of that or at least the last step.
I think my code is not clean :/